# Chome tabs not filling tab bar

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, browser-tabs

I recently got a laptop (XPS 15) with 3200 * 1800 screen.

After updating drivers, `Chrome` looks like:
[image: Tabs stacked but not filling screen]

The tabs won't fill the red part of the screen.

I tried the follows in `about:flags` with no luck:

- Enabled HiDPI setting - resulted in a very bad layout.
- Enabled Stacked Tabs - resulted in the above picture, tabs stacked but not fitting whole width.
- Played with touch screen options, no luck, context menu made larger, so does the tabs but still not fitting whole width. (Touch Optimized UI and Enable touch event)
- Reseting to factory default - no luck.
- Changed the `Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays` which was suggested in the duplicated question with no luck.

Any idea how to make tabs fit whole bar ?

EDIT: Using Windows 8.1

Comment: Open a bounty on the duplicate quesiton. It doesn't look like it got much attention in the past. :c

Comment: The point is all of my tries above can be an answer to the duplicated question, none of them worked for me.